# R buffer geospatial points

Tags: r, geospatial

I am currently trying to create (100m) buffer around points in R.
I have found two very usefull answers, but I still have problems.
Here the answers I found:
[Buffer (geo)spatial points in R with gbuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411251/buffer-geospatial-points-in-r-with-gbuffer?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Create buffer and count points in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524328/create-buffer-and-count-points-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My problem is that when I create my buffer, I only have one big buffer.

ANFR_IDF is a dataframe. The column "ID" is a unique ID, the column "coordonnees" the coordinates.

```
ANFR_IDF$lat=as.numeric(gsub(",.*$", "", ANFR_IDF$coordonnees))
ANFR_IDF$lon=as.numeric(gsub(".*, ", "", ANFR_IDF$coordonnees))
coordinates( ANFR_IDF ) <- c( "lon", "lat" )
CRS=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
proj4string(ANFR_IDF)=CRS

ANFR_IDF <- spTransform(ANFR_IDF,CRS)
test2=gBuffer( ANFR_IDF, width=100,id=ANFR_IDF$ID, byid=TRUE )
```

Any idea of what can be the problem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a geographic coordinate system with units in decimal degrees so when you provide `100` for the `width` parameter, it creates a 100 decimal degree buffer (one huge buffer!). Try projecting first

```
library(sp)
ANFR_IDF_prj <- spTransform(ANFR_IDF, crs([your preferred projection]))
test2=gBuffer( ANFR_IDF_prj, width=100,id=ANFR_IDF_prj$ID, byid=TRUE )
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, it works perfectly and I understand what was the problem!