# Difficulty with gBuffer in R: Resulting buffer is incorrect size

Tags: r, geolocation, buffer

The overall goal of this code is to generate random points within a circular buffer based around a single lat/long point which I will enter in as needed. My apparent issue is that the buffer generated from `gBuffer` is not the correct size/location and therefore the points are farther than desired from the input location.

I am attempting to create a 130 meter buffer around a point. To construct my code I have been using `44.55555, -68.55555`. I am using decimal degrees lat/long as that is what my data is in.

I have tried multiple stackoverflow threads to find the answer including:
[Buffer (geo)spatial points in R with gbuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411251/buffer-geospatial-points-in-r-with-gbuffer)
[Create buffer and count points in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524328/create-buffer-and-count-points-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
#Enter in the lat and Long
NestLat <- readline(prompt="Enter Nest Latitude:") #Use 44.55555 
NestLong <- readline(prompt="Enter Nest Longitude:") #Use -68.55555

#Coordinate from text to spatial points
NestLat <- as.numeric(NestLat)
NestLong <- as.numeric(NestLong)

nestcoords <- cbind(NestLat, NestLong)
nestcoords_sp <- SpatialPoints(nestcoords, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
nestcoords_sp <- spTransform(nestcoords_sp, CRS("+init=epsg:2960"))

#Create buffer to generate 3 random points within 130m of nest
nestbuffer130 <- gBuffer(nestcoords_sp, width = 130)
nestbuffer130 <- spTransform(nestbuffer130, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

randoms130 <- spsample(nestbuffer130, 3, type = "random")
randoms130 <- spTransform(randoms130, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

nestbuffer130spdf <- as(nestbuffer130, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
randoms130 <- as(randoms130, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")
```

The final buffer seems to be a circle with radius of 335 and not placed in the correct location spatially.

Answer (score 0):

How are you measuring radius? The code seems to work just fine if you just want the sample points in the right location. Here is your code slightly modified with the gDistance function showing that your points are within the buffer zone. SF is now the preferred spatial package for R and the syntax is clearer and easier. I added what your code would look like with the SF package.

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
#Enter in the lat and Long
NestLat <- 44.55555 
NestLong <- -68.55555

#Coordinate from text to spatial points
NestLat <- as.numeric(NestLat)
NestLong <- as.numeric(NestLong)

nestcoords <- cbind(NestLat, NestLong)
nestcoords_sp <- SpatialPoints(nestcoords, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
nestcoords_sp <- spTransform(nestcoords_sp, CRS("+init=epsg:2960"))

#Create buffer to generate 3 random points within 130m of nest
nestbuffer130 <- gBuffer(nestcoords_sp, width = 130)
randoms130 <- spsample(nestbuffer130, 3, type = "random")
nestbuffer130spdf <- as(nestbuffer130, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
randoms130 <- as(randoms130, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")

# measure distance
gDistance(randoms130, nestcoords_sp, byid = T)
```

SF

```
library(sf)
# turn coordinates into spatial poitns using sf
NestLat <- 44.55555 
NestLong <- -68.55555
nestPoints <- st_point(c(NestLong,NestLat)) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 2960)
mapview(randoms130) + nestPoints

#Create buffer to generate 3 random points within 130m of nest
nestbuffer130 <- st_buffer(nestPoints, dist = 130)
randoms130 <- st_sample(nestbuffer130, 3)

# measure distance between points
st_distance(nestPoints,randoms130)
nestbuffer130SF <- st_sf(data = data.frame(ID = 1:length(randoms130)),
                         geometry = randoms130, crs = st_crs(randoms130)) %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 4326)

# check data visually
library(mapview)
mapview(nestbuffer130SF) + nestPoints
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments/checking my work. For whatever reason I thought the code was incorrect because I was entering the points into google earth and measuring the distance and they were some were 200-300m away from the input coordinates. When running your simplified version it appears to work fine.

Comment: No problem. That's strange that google earth was showing the points so far off. I wonder if it is an issue of projection? Good luck with your work.